# What determines tag order and the tag used in the browser titlebar?

Tags: bug

My recent question [How might I measure the proportion of a ride spent in various hand positions, or has it been studied?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/76853/7309) has 3 tags.  I added them in the order [drop-bar], [riding-position], [long-distance]; the latter is the least relevant and was an afterthought.

The browser titlebar reads "long distance - How might I measure..." which isn't particularly helpful, and the tags have been reordered to put [long-distance] first.  I've noticed this before, but rarely has it been so clearly the least relevant tag that's used first, and never on one of my questions.  I'm almost tempted to remove the tag.

So what's the logic behind the ordering of tags?  Reordering seems like a bug given that the new first tag is used as part of the page title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tags are sorted on the question according to popularity of each tag (and has for [over ten years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50819/294691)).

In your example, the [long-distance](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/long-distance) tag has 88 questions, [riding-position](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riding-position) 63, and [drop-bar](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drop-bar) has 30. Since the long distance tag has the most questions, it's put first and then used in the page title.

Unfortunately, there's no way to get around this system.

Comment: And I see from your link that people complained then too!  I'm likely to have contributed to the stats being the way they are myself.  I think the solution here is to remove it

Comment: Interesting - now it's using [drop-bar] when I'd have expected [riding-position]

Comment: Huh, that is interesting. I'm not sure why that's the case.

Comment: So you're saying the bug has a bug ?